# how can i use iptables to allow a particular url?

Tags: linux

I want to allow a particular site using iptables. Am running debian squeeze in my proxy server. I have tried giving the IP address of the website .Since, its changing dynamically for popular sites , I can't get it working. Is there any way to allow the url in iptables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layer 3 devices do not understand higher level application data. (URL's) What you are asking however, can be configured in your proxy server.

Comment: oh fine. I can get you. You are asking me to configure my 'squid' to allow the particular url ?

Comment: Yes, Squid is more than capable of Blocking/Allowing URL's. if I remember correctly, you can easily create something similar to an access control list and then reference that file in your squid.conf. A google ought to yield some proper instruction.